# Output specific variables from json file

Tags: php, json

I'm a real newbie with php, but i'm just trying to learn it by doing please help me by showing me how to load a whole json file and output only the variable that contain the name:

let say my  file.json contain:

> {"type":"FeatureC”,”features":[
>   {"type":"Feature","id”:”gf”,”properties":{"name”:”USA”},”geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072],[62.230651,35.270664],[62.984662,35.404041],[63.193538,35.857166],[63.982896,36.007957],[64.546479,36.312073],[64.746105,37.111818],[65.588948,37.305217],[65.745631,37.661164],[66.217385,37.39379],[66.518607,37.362784],[67.075782,37.356144],[67.83,37.144994],[68.135562,37.023115],[68.859446,37.344336],[69.196273,37.151144],[69.518785,37.608997],[70.116578,37.588223],[70.270574,37.735165],[70.376304,38.138396],[70.806821,38.486282],[71.348131,38.258905],[71.239404,37.953265],[71.541918,37.905774],[71.448693,37.065645],[71.844638,36.738171],[72.193041,36.948288],[72.63689,37.047558],[73.260056,37.495257],[73.948696,37.421566],[74.980002,37.41999],[75.158028,37.133031],[74.575893,37.020841],[74.067552,36.836176],[72.920025,36.720007],[71.846292,36.509942],[71.262348,36.074388],[71.498768,35.650563],[71.613076,35.153203],[71.115019,34.733126],[71.156773,34.348911],[70.881803,33.988856],[69.930543,34.02012],[70.323594,33.358533],[69.687147,33.105499],[69.262522,32.501944],[69.317764,31.901412],[68.926677,31.620189],[68.556932,31.71331],[67.792689,31.58293],[67.683394,31.303154],[66.938891,31.304911],[66.381458,30.738899],[66.346473,29.887943],[65.046862,29.472181],[64.350419,29.560031],[64.148002,29.340819],[63.550261,29.468331],[62.549857,29.318572],[60.874248,29.829239],[61.781222,30.73585],[61.699314,31.379506],[60.941945,31.548075],[60.863655,32.18292],[60.536078,32.981269],[60.9637,33.528832],[60.52843,33.676446],[60.803193,34.404102],[61.210817,35.650072]]]}},
>   {"type":"Feature","id”:”sa”,”properties":{"name":"Zimbabwe"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[31.191409,-22.25151],[30.659865,-22.151567],[30.322883,-22.271612],[29.839037,-22.102216],[29.432188,-22.091313],[28.794656,-21.639454],[28.02137,-21.485975],[27.727228,-20.851802],[27.724747,-20.499059],[27.296505,-20.39152],[26.164791,-19.293086],[25.850391,-18.714413],[25.649163,-18.536026],[25.264226,-17.73654],[26.381935,-17.846042],[26.706773,-17.961229],[27.044427,-17.938026],[27.598243,-17.290831],[28.467906,-16.4684],[28.825869,-16.389749],[28.947463,-16.043051],[29.516834,-15.644678],[30.274256,-15.507787],[30.338955,-15.880839],[31.173064,-15.860944],[31.636498,-16.07199],[31.852041,-16.319417],[32.328239,-16.392074],[32.847639,-16.713398],[32.849861,-17.979057],[32.654886,-18.67209],[32.611994,-19.419383],[32.772708,-19.715592],[32.659743,-20.30429],[32.508693,-20.395292],[32.244988,-21.116489],[31.191409,-22.25151]]]}}
>
> ]}

and in my output.php it should output the names like:

NAME: USA
NAME: Zimbabwe

from the json file, please show me example to understand and advance my skills into the php world.

Comment: your json have problems, can you updated the json please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = json_decode($your_json);
$type = $data->type;
var_dump($type); //
```

You can read more about decoding json in php and accessing values [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: do you test your code?

Comment: i only whant to echo names